# Interact with rect to take me to another page HTML JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

#### The Menu

[image]

I want to make it so when the user clicks play it takes you to another HTML page. I have placed a rect over the play area and want to make it so the rect is what the user is clicking as the play text is part of a single image.

This is the JS for my rect:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Red rectangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "6";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.rect(125, 140, 230, 90);  
 ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: A canvas is just a drawing surface.  To make the rectangle clickable, you need to handle click events on the canvas itself and check the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;

function draw() {
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "6";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.rect(101, 114, 184, 71);
    ctx.stroke();
}

img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3x29.jpg';

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.offsetX > 102 && e.offsetX < 286 && e.offsetY > 110 && e.offsetY < 182) {
        window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com'; // another html page location
    }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```